# Linux Mint 17-18 freezing randomly

Tags: linux, linux-mint, freeze, nvidia-graphics-card

I am totally desperate and just a tiny hair far from using some other OS instead of Linux because it is giving me a headache.
So the thing is, I am using Linux Mint from version 17 and at the moment I have the version 18 installed and nothing have changed. So after fresh install (not using swap partition but only home and root), I am getting random freezes all the time. Sometimes it works for a day, sometimes it freezes multiple times per day and so on.

Freeze means -> keyboard and mouse is not responding and that's it. The only way is to shut it down with a power button hold. (CTRL + ALT + F1... doesn't work obviously). Sometimes I can even reboot with (ALT + PRINTSCREEN) + R E I U S B combination but very rarely. Then on different computers there are different behaviours. On some computer the Linux doesn't boot properly for 3 times in a row because I get some errors with nouveau issues constantly popping in the console.

I tried these bumblebees, proprietary drivers and so on and nothing helps. Actually there is not a way that I haven't tried. I went through all the solutions until year 2011 or even less but not even one solution helped me.

Since that issue is present on 5th computer in a row, I am really not sure what am I doing wrong or what is wrong with the distribution.

Have anyone had such experience with it? I also tried raw Debian and I also experienced these issues, mostly with graphic card drivers.

It would be really good if someone finally clarify that what is happening there actually.

Thank you very much in advance!